Assistance Needed to Connect Company Database to Power BI
I am a beginner Power BI developer and have been working on creating dashboards using Excel data. We now want to automate our reports by directly connecting to our company database.
HeidiSQL has been installed on my system, and I can access the database through it. However, I am facing challenges in connecting this database to Power BI.
Could you please guide me through setting up the connection between Power BI and our company database? I would greatly appreciate any documentation or step-by-step instructions.
Thank you for your support!

To access on-premises data from the cloud Power BI Service, you will need to install the free Data Gateway. The download and documentation are available in the Power BI Service.

